# Automapper - Mapping Non-Related Properties by Id

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I am developing an ASP.Net Core Web API using Visual Studio 2017 and Entity Framework.

I have the following `InitialDeviceLocation` entity:

```
    public class InitialDeviceLocation
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CampaignId")]
    public Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
    public Guid CampaignId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
}
```

I want Automapper to lookup the `DeviceName` and the `LocationName` as it maps the entity to my DTO but cannot figure out the mapping.

I cannot set `DeviceId` and `LocationId` as Foreign Keys because this would create circular relationships. I assumed that Automapper could simply lookup these fields so that I could make them available for the client.

I tried using `.ForMember` but as I don't have a `Device` object or a `Location` object in my entity definition I couldn't see how to do this.

Here is my `Device` entity definition, `Locations` is very similar:

```
    public class Device
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DeviceTypeId")]
    public DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
    public int DeviceTypeId { get; set; }

    public string Ident { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DefaultLocationId { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions very welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add the `Device` and `Location` entities in `InitialDeviceLocation`.

```
public class InitialDeviceLocation
{
    // Other properties

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your DTO, you can put properties called `DeviceName` and `LocationName`. AutoMapper will recognize the convention of `[ClassName][PropertyName]` automatically and do the mapping for you.

```
public class InitialDeviceLocationDTO
{
    // Other properties

    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion, I'll try it and get back to you.